# Splitting Japanese characters in Python

Tags: python, asianfonts

I have a list of Japanese Kanji characters that are separated by a symbol that looks like a comma.  I would like to use a split function to get the information stored in a list.

If the text was in English then i would like to the following:

```
x = 'apple,pear,orange'
x.split(',')
```

However, this does not work for the following:

```
japanese = '東北カネカ売，フジヤ商店，橋谷，旭販売，東洋装'
```

I have set the encoding to

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

and I am able to read in the Japanese characters fine.

Answer (score 3):

It's not actually [a comma](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff0c/index.htm):

```
>>> u'，'
    u'\uff0c'
```

If you make the string unicode, you can split it just fine:

```
>>> u'東北カネカ売，フジヤ商店，橋谷，旭販売，東洋装'.split(u'，')
    [u'\u6771\u5317\u30ab\u30cd\u30ab\u58f2',
 u'\u30d5\u30b8\u30e4\u5546\u5e97',
 u'\u6a4b\u8c37',
 u'\u65ed\u8ca9\u58f2',
 u'\u6771\u6d0b\u88c5']
```

Python 3 works as well:

```
>>> '東北カネカ売，フジヤ商店，橋谷，旭販売，東洋装'.split('，')
    ['東北カネカ売', 'フジヤ商店', '橋谷', '旭販売', '東洋装']
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
for j in japanese.split('\xef\xbc\x8c'): print j
```

The "comma" here is `'\xef\xbc\x8c'`.